# An exception occured during performFiltering() -AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, autocomplete, autocompletetextview

I have an auto complete text view that is somehow failing to filter through the string array . As suggested in other posts I thoroughly checked if there were any null values in my array but there were none.

This is the error I am getting

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter$ArrayFilter.performFiltering(ArrayAdapter.java:480)
  at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                          at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

This is my code below

```
DataUsageController duc = new DataUsageController(context);
     String costCentreString = duc.costCentreString;
     String[] strs = costCentreString.split(",,");
      String[]costCentreList = new String[costCentreString.length()];
      for (int i=0; i < strs.length ; i++) {
         costCentreList[i] = strs[i];
      }
      et_client=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.et_client);
      AutoCompleteTextView actv  = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.et_client);
      actv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.costcentrelist__details, costCentreList));
      et_client=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.et_client);
      actv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.costcentrelist__details , costCentreList));
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,costCentreList);
```

and this is my auto complete TextView in the XML

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/et_client"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     </AutoCompleteTextView>
```

Comment: Once you set the adapter why do you have this  `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,costCentreList);`?

Comment: why do you have two reference of one auto complete text view? one is local and one is global

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks for pointing that out let me take off that line and see what happens

Comment: I took that line out but I still get the same error

Comment: check the content of `costCentreList` array if it has any `null`s

Comment: the array has no nulls . I have discovered that the problem is with this line so I am trying to figure out how to correctly declare the size of this array        `String[]costCentreList = new String[costCentreString.length()];`

Comment: @pskink not it does not have nulls the problem was with the size of the array I had specified it to match the size of the string which is wrong . I have since adjusted it